# wowza: how to stream to very large audience?

Tags: wowza

My customer wants to organize a live conference which will be stream to
2000-4000 people online. (he will do that 1 per month)
I don't think I can just use 1 server with wowza.

What would be the suitable/simplest solution ?
I heard something like amazon EC2 : can someone help me and help me to
choose the right solution/infrastructure to live stream to 2000-4000
persons.

Does EC2 automatically resizes its bandwidth according to number of viewers
?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) to split your traffic between your users so that no one server is stressed. If you're doing it internationally, you can also use [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to automatically route users to the closest server to them.

Or if you want to do the same thing without having to be dependent on AWS, Wowza has a solution for this as well, [Dynamic Load Balancing](http://www.wowza.com/products/addons/dynamic-load-balancing-solution).

When using Wowza's solution, it looks like you could also use this feature to distribute your live stream across all of those servers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd most definitely use a CDN. You can simply push a stream to a CDN, or let the CDN pull a stream from your encoder / media server. There's no need for ELB, Route 53 or DLB. A single EC2 instance connected to [CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) will do. If you don't want to go AWS, then choose another CDN like BitGravity, Edgecast, StreamZilla, Limewire, etc. etc. Wowza has built-in support for connecting a stream to a CDN.

However, there are solutions where you won't even need a media server. There are several [services on the web](https://www.google.com/?q=live%20streaming%20services&gws_rd=ssl#q=live%20streaming%20services) that can help you publish a stream and distribute it to 1000s of users.